# NSDateFormatter timezone (Etc/GMT) not getting parsed for dateFromString

Tags: iphone, datetime, timezone

I am getting nil for trying to convert this `2011-07-11 13:28:59 Etc/GMT` into a NSDate by the following code

```
NSString *dateString=@"2011-07-11 13:28:59 Etc/GMT";
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z"];
NSDate *purchaseDate = [dateformatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

This date is coming from apple server itself for in-app purchase validation. I've gone about lot of threads with timezone. but none of them show how to convert this `Etc/GMT`

i have tried `z` `zz` `zzz` `zzzz` `Z` `ZZ` `ZZZ` `ZZZZ`

what might be the issue here.

Comment: pueden ayudarme con estan pregunta 

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162835/how-to-use-nsdateformatter-to-venezuela

gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *dateString=@"2011-07-11 13:28:59 Etc/GMT";
dateString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Etc/GMT" withString:@"GMT"];
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];

// Or stuff....>>

NSDate *date = [dateformatter dateFromString: dateString];
NSLog(@"You may Need This  =========%@",date);
dateformatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];

NSString *convertedString = [dateformatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
```

/// may help =====>>  http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/

Comment: This works! I did go through the above document and also [Time_Zone_fallback](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Time_Zone_Fallback), but its quite hard to comprehend. I still do not get why `Etc/GMT` is returned instead of `GMT` and what is difference between `Etc/GMT*` and just plain `GMT`

Comment: Word of warning, Etc/GMT and GMT are not the same thing.

Comment: Etc/GMT is not strictly the same thing as UTC or GMT. ... For example, TZ='Etc/GMT+4' uses the abbreviation "GMT+4" and corresponds to 4 hours behind UTC (i.e. west of Greenwich) even though many people would expect it to mean 4 hours ahead of UTC (i.e. east of Greenwich).

Answer (score 17):

The correct `dateFormat` is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV` which is what you should use to solve your problem.

Comment: Amazing! Couldn't find this anywhere - THANK YOU

Answer (score 9):

// Swift Version

```
    let DateString = "2016-01-21 00:29:09 Etc/GMT"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
    var dateObject = dateFormatter.date(from: DateString)
```