# how to use nsdateformatter to Venezuela

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsdateformatter, nslocale

I'm trying to schedule a date on the calendar, which has a start time and an end time, everything works fine if the time zone is in the U.S., and the date the change does not help and I need it to Venezuela what should I do as I place generica, to serve me anywhere no matter the time zone?

here I leave the code as data and bring me as I make the date format.

```
 comes the date in the following format: 12/10/2012 05:00 pm

  EKEvent* event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
  horafin = [dateFormatter dateFromString:inicio];
horafin  = [horafin dateByAddingTimeInterval:3600];
horainicio = [dateFormatter dateFromString:inicio];
[dateFormatter release];


NSString *ti=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:title];
NSLog(@"");
event.title =@"juego";
event.startDate = horainicio;
event.endDate = horafin;
event.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pagina.com"];
event.notes = ti;
event.allDay = NO;
vc.event = event;
vc.editViewDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The event calendar call me correctly only fails when you change the time zone, as I did not take the date correctly I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use following code to get desired timezone-converted datetime:

```
- (NSString *) getUTCDate : (NSString *) inputDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *utcDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [utcDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    [utcDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
  //  [utcDateFormatter setTimeZone :[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT: 0]];        
    // utc format
    NSDate *dateInUTC = [utcDateFormatter dateFromString: inputDate];        

    return dateInUTC;
}
```

where `dateInUTC` is the date in GMT timezone.

You need to replace your own timezone in call `[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change one line of code in your code...

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

This will set time format in universal which doesnot change with region or day light saving time.